# Creating LinkField from XML

Tags: links, fieldtype

Sitecoore 9: I need to create a LinkField from a general link's xml

E.g.

```
<link
text="Text"
linktype="internal/external"
url="url"
anchor="anchor"
title="title"
class="class"
querystring="querystring"
target="target"
id="id" />
```

But I can only create a link field based on an id which I don't have without parsing this xml string.

How can I create a LinkField from this xml? Ultimately, Im trying to get the url for this General Link and I only have access to the xml

Comment: When you say _"I only have access to the xml"_, are you retrieving this via the Sitecore API only some other way (static string from somewhere)? Without running this through the API, you cannot get URL from ID alone (since you also need to figure out the parents at minimum)

Comment: The xml originates from a custom built Sitecore ORM but not sure the relevance of this. Given the link xml, I want to get the url - I assume the easiest way to do those would be by creating a LinkField object..

Comment: The relevance being I'm trying to understand whether the code you are running has Sitecore context and access to the API or whether it's from non-Sitecore code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In theory you can extend `LinkUrl` class and pass the xml instead of the `LinkField` object like that:

```
using System.Xml;
using Sitecore.Data;
using Sitecore.Xml.Xsl;

namespace My.Assembly.Namespace
{
    public class ExtendedLinkUrl : LinkUrl
    {
        public string GetUrl(string linkFieldXml, Database database)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(linkFieldXml) || database == null)
                return null;

            var xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDocument.LoadXml(linkFieldXml);
            var linkElement = xmlDocument.DocumentElement;

            if (linkElement == null)
                return null;

            string linkType = linkElement.GetAttribute("linktype");
            string url = linkElement.GetAttribute("url");
            string id = linkElement.GetAttribute("id");
            string anchor = linkElement.GetAttribute("anchor");
            string queryString = linkElement.GetAttribute("querystring");

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(anchor))
                anchor = "#" + anchor;

            switch (linkType)
            {
                case "anchor":
                    return anchor;
                case "external":
                    return GetExternalUrl(url);
                case "internal":
                    return GetInternalUrl(database, url, id, anchor, queryString);
                case "javascript":
                    return GetJavaScriptUrl(url);
                case "mailto":
                    return GetMailToLink(url);
                case "media":
                    return GetMediaUrl(database, id);
                default:
                    return string.Empty;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you - seems to be working on first test ..